# magick convert png to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, bluehost

i have problem with magick tool on php
use this tool on my laptop and my server (bluehost)
the weird part is the function work on laptop but it doesn't work on the server
here command on my laptop

```
$gp= "C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\convert.exe ";
    $ch=" -density 300  upload\\temp_img\\*.png";
    $ch.="  upload\\pdf_created\\".$id_pro."_".$id.".pdf";

     $gp=escapeshellarg($gp);
     echo exec($gp.$ch);
```

and the command on the server

```
   $gp= "convert   upload/temp_img/*.png upload/pdf_create/".$id_pro."_".$id.".pdf";
     echo shell_exec($gp);
```

in addition to this problem

```
convert -resize
```

doesn't work on the server 
but i used other function to resize

Answer (score 1):

Imagemagick is a raster image processor only. PDF is not a raster image, therefore it has to be converted to it before further processing. Imagemagick uses ghostscript to handle this.

So if you can convert images like jpg's with the mentioned command, but not pdf's, it's very likely that ghostscript is missing.

Comment: do you know how to add ghostscript in bluehost ?

Comment: Ghostscript has to be installed like imagemagick or any other server software by an administrator.

Comment: after few looking in ssh 
i found the ghostscript is already installed !!

Comment: Then either your path is wrong and you are not able to convert images at all (have you ever tried that as mentioned in my answer?), or imagemagick is compiled without ghostscript support. It that case you can convert pdf with ghostscript beforehand and let imagemagick do its job afterwards.

Comment: i create new question, i tried new thing 
each one have different error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071589/php-magick-jpg-to-pdf-error

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the path on the server, On server there is no "C:\Program Files (x86)" path.

Give the relative path like this

```
 $path= realpath(__DIR__.'/../'));
```

Comment: the server using linux

Comment: No problem if its linux, give realpath.

Comment: to get realpath for convert
i have to write realpath("convert") ?